# Google Script: i can not assign a value to a key of an object

Tags: javascript, object, key

I have a simple object in JS, with years as keys, and inside the months. Inside every month, I want to store information. Here is my object:

```
function generateYearMonths() {
  var firstYear = 2012;
  var todayDate = new Date(Date());
  var lastYear = todayDate.getYear();
  var yearsMonths = {}

  var months = {}

  for(var x=1; x<=12; x++) {
    months[x.toString()] = {
      totalExpenses: 0,
      totalIncomes: 0,
      totalBalance: 0
    }
  }

  for(var x=firstYear; x<=lastYear; x++) {
    yearsMonths[x] = months
  }

  return yearsMonths;
}
```

I want to assign to a year, and a month, for example year 2012, month 1, which are keys, a value. I do that:

```
yearsMonths[2012][1]["totalExpenses"] = 23;
```

And the value 23 is assigned to every year in the month 1. I don't understand where is the error. I am trying Google script for the first time, I don't know what I am doing wrong, I just want to update the hash with values. But for every year-month pair key, not overwrite every single month.

Please help.

EDIT -- move months into loop form years

```
function generateYearMonths() {
  var firstYear = 2012;
  var todayDate = new Date(Date());
  var lastYear = todayDate.getYear();
  lastYear = 2013;
  var yearsMonths = {}

  for(var x=firstYear; x<=lastYear; x++) {

    var months = {}

    for(var x=1; x<=12; x++) {
      months[x.toString()] = {
        totalExpenses: 0,
        totalIncomes: 0,
        totalBalance: 0
      }
    }
    yearsMonths[x] = months
  }

  return yearsMonths;
}
```

Now I don't assign the same value to every month, because the script runs infinitely...

Comment: That's because you're assigning to the same object `months` for all the years in the line `yearsMonths[x] = months`. They are all the same object hence any change to `months` in one year is reflected over all years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are passed by *reference* in Javascript, not by value. You only ever have one `var months = {}` object referenced throughout the entire script, so when you do

```
for(var x=firstYear; x<=lastYear; x++) {
  yearsMonths[x] = months
}
```

*every* `yearMonths[x]` is referencing the same *singular* `months` object. Deep clone `months` instead, to ensure that every item in the `yearMonths` array references a unique object:

```
for(var x=firstYear; x<=lastYear; x++) {
  yearsMonths[x] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(months));
}
```

Comment: I have moved the var months = {} and the loop for the 12 months inside the loop of every year. This way, I am initializing a variable in every year loop. But it's not working. Am I not initializing a new variable everytime I do var?

Comment: it worked. Is there a alternative? does stringify create a new object then?

Comment: Yes, stringifying and then parsing that string creates a deep copy of the object.